# How to prevent :pseudo elements dynamically chance position when a scrollbar appears?

Tags: css

When a scrollbar appears, `:pseudo` elements inside a `relative` positioned `element` are not on the desired place anymore.

Instead, they are just flowing somewhere inside the `element`.

Lets say i have the following markup. As you can see, the `:pseudo` elements nicely stick to the edges of the element.

***Snippet where the `:pseudo`'s are well positioned, if there is no scrollbar***

```css
.without-scroll-bar {
  border: 5px solid green;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.without-scroll-bar:before,
.without-scroll-bar:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

.without-scroll-bar:before {
  border-top: 5px solid red;
  border-right: 5px solid red;
  top: -5px;right: -5px;
}

.without-scroll-bar:after {
  border-right: 5px solid red;
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
  bottom: -5px;right: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="without-scroll-bar">
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
</div>
```

However, when i make the `element` have a fixed `max-height`, so if it reaches it, it shows a scrollbar. The `:pseudo` elements are not nicely positioned anymore. They are just flowing somewhere inside its container.

***Snippet where the `:pseudo`'s are not positioned as disired***

```css
code {
  background: #ededed;
  padding: 3px;
}

.with-scroll-bar {
  border: 5px solid green;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.with-scroll-bar:before,
.with-scroll-bar:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

.with-scroll-bar:before {
  border-top: 5px solid red;
  border-right: 5px solid red;
  top: -5px;right: -5px;
}

.with-scroll-bar:after {
  border-right: 5px solid red;
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
  bottom: -5px;right: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="with-scroll-bar">
  <p>As you can see, the <code>:pseudo</code> elements are not in position anymore</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
</div>
```

- How can i prevent this?
- How can i make the layout i want, also applies on `elements` with scrollbars?
- Even better, how can i make the `:pseudo` elements remain on the edges? Like the first snippet, but then also with a scrollbar on its container?

***Oh, i should note that i dont have access to the `HTML` itself. So i cannot just wrap a `div` around it and then add the `:pseudo` elements on that `div`.***

Comment: Maybe put the pseudo elements in the first and last children of the container? The thing is, the container is 300px long, so the :after element positions itself at 300px, and if you can't use an additional container, the :after element will always be at 300px.

Comment: Adding a wrapper above the parent div will do, check answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### JavaScript

If you can use JavaScript another way would be to make use of the [wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function from jQuery and add the pseudo elements later on to this wrapper div. So there is still no need to change anything in your HTML structure since JavaScript will do this for you.

**JS**

```
$(".with-scroll-bar").wrap("<div id='wrapper' />");
```

```js
$(".with-scroll-bar").wrap("<div id='wrapper' />");
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

code {
  background: #ededed;
  padding: 3px;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.with-scroll-bar {
  border: 5px solid green;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#wrapper:before,
#wrapper:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#wrapper:before {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 5px solid red;
  border-right: 5px solid red;
}

#wrapper:after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-right: 5px solid red;
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is just some example text.</p>
<p>This is just some example text.</p>

<div class="with-scroll-bar">
  <p>As you can see, the <code>:pseudo</code> elements are not in position anymore</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
</div>
```

### CSS

There is also another solution with pure CSS but this one is very very hacky. This only works in Chrome as far as I could see and it doesn't support dynamic height of the div. This means when there is no scrollbar the layout will break.

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

code {
  background: #ededed;
  padding: 3px;
}

.with-scroll-bar {
  border: 5px solid green;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.with-scroll-bar:before,
.with-scroll-bar:after {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  align-self: flex-end;
  content: "";
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

.with-scroll-bar:before {
  border-top: 5px solid red;
  border-right: 5px solid red;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: 34px;
}

.with-scroll-bar:after {
  border-right: 5px solid red;
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
  margin-top: 295px;
  margin-left: 34px;
}
```

```html
<p>This is just some example text.</p>
<p>This is just some example text.</p>
<div class="with-scroll-bar">
  <p>As you can see, the <code>:pseudo</code> elements are not in position anymore</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Great to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

The Idea is you have to skip the use of Pseudo altogether,
What you can do is append two elements using `Javascript` one at the beginning another at the end.

Since `:Pseudo elements` are never attached to DOM, you need these elements to manipulate the positions of your newly added Elements to match your Requirement

[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ShekharPankaj/617dh6hd/2/)

there are some edge cases in above example, and those two buttons are just to change the height of your parent div.
You will get the basic idea and would need to fix them accordingly.

Comment: I can't access the HTML itself. Like i said in my question. I added this later, so i might have missed it. So my guess is, ive no other option than what you said i should do.

Comment: In that case you need to use Javascript to change the position of your pesudo element in case of change in height of `div.with-scroll-bar`

Comment: How do i access a pseudo in javascript? As far as i know there i can't apply css to pseudo elements through javascript right?

Comment: @RichardMauritz, there are some hacks, but look at the fiddle link

Comment: Ah, you create dummy elements to act as the pseudo's. Pretty smart though. It does work, ill upvote for now. If no one is comming with a simpler anwser ill accept it. Thanks for writing that piece of code though. It must have took you some time, I appreciate that very much!

Answer (score 0):

As can be easily seen by making the pseudoelements more visible (e.g. border on all four sides) they are laid out in the same way as when max-height isn't reached: at the corners of the space the element occupies, not at the top and bottom of its content.

Predictable layouts include position:fixed or, like in the following, placing the pseudoelements inline. What are you using the pseudoelements for?

```css
code {
  background: #ededed;
  padding: 3px;
}
 .with-scroll-bar p{
margin:15px;
}
.with-scroll-bar {
  border: 5px solid green;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto; 

}

.with-scroll-bar:before,
.with-scroll-bar:after {
  border: 5px solid red;
display:block;
    content: "";
  height: 20px;
  
 


}

  .with-scroll-bar:before 
 {

left:0px;
width:20px;
  margin:0px;


}   

.with-scroll-bar:after {
 
left:0px;
right:0px;
  margin:0px;


}
```

```html
<div class="with-scroll-bar">
  <p>As you can see, the <code>:pseudo</code> elements are not in position anymore</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
  <p>This is just some example text.</p>
</div>
```